# Codeigniter Validation form not working

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I know that this problem is in some other question, but I can't figure it out how to handle it properly in my case. I've been searching for a while, and I can't find the solution:

I want to do one form and connect with my database, but something goes wrong and it's impossible to receive the values on the database.

Here it's the view (location: /application/view/pages/home.php):

```
<?php echo validation_errors();?>
<div id="signup" style='position: absolute; left:900px; top: 380px;'>
<?php echo form_open('user/signup');?>

<input type='text' required="required" placeholder="Full Name" name="fullname"/><br/>
<input type='text' required="required" placeholder="Email" name="email"/><br/>
<input type='text' required="required" placeholder="Password" name="password"/><br/>
<input type='text' required="required" placeholder="Confirm password" name="confirmpassword"/><br/>
<button type="submit" name="submit_signup">Sign up</button>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Here the controller (location: /application/controllers/user.php):

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('User_model');
    }

    public index(){

            $this->load->view('view');

    }


    public function signup(){

            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->model('User_model');


            $user_id = DEFAULT;

            $data = array(){

            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'full_name' => $this->input->post('fullname')

            }
        $this->User_model->add_user($data);
        $this->index();
     }
     }
```

And the model (location: /application/models/user_model.php):

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->database();
        }

        public function add_user($data){

        $this->load->database();

        $this->db->insert('user',$data);

        }

}
?>
```

Comment: No need to load your database in your model constructor, then again in your add_user function.

Comment: would you please share your database schema?

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your array:

It should be:

```
$data = array(
  'user_id' => $user_id,
  'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
  'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
  'full_name' => $this->input->post('fullname')
)
```

If still didn't work, your `$user_id` is probably an INT type, so just give it some `INT`.

And you are not doing any validation at all!?

Comment: Okey, I correct it. Sorry I'm a noobie on CodeIgniter and I have some things that I don't know how exactly works. The form_open have to connect with the controller class right? After the form, the page redirects to the controller, but this one don't get the values of the form or something and can't redirect to the 'success page'.
I made a new controller class called 'sign_up' that looks like the post of Wide Vision

Comment: I get this error everytime that I execute the controller: Class 'CI_Controller' not found